# How to save multiple take at once in Slick

Tags: scala, slick

I am pretty new to Scala and Slick and trying to pickup my concepts. I am wondering how can I save multiple tables here with one command. i.e. I have an email system which has Folders and Messages table. My Folders table can have many Messages. I would like to save a folders and can all the messages be saved on it's own. Something like hibernate where we specify the mapping and it takecare of multiple saves or deletes or updates based on our relationships and mapping.

Thanks for your time in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Slick is closer to the database engine than traditional ORM tools like hibernate. So how would we solve this in traditional database engine without ORM?

Using SQL:

We would create tables holding information about Folders and Messages

```
CREATE TABLE Folder (
    ID int not null primary key autoincrement,
    Name string not null
    --etc
)
CREATE TABLE Message (
    ID int not null primary key autoincrement,
    FolderID int not null foreign key references Folder(ID),
    Sender string not null,
    Content string not null
    --etc
)
```

Now what would we want to do with these tables? 
We probably want to display a list of all folders

```
SELECT ID, Name FROM Folder
```

We would like to display all messages in a given Folder

```
SELECT ID, Sender, Content FROM Message WHERE FolderID = ?
```

We would like to create a new folder

```
INSERT INTO Folder (Name) VALUES (?)
```

Add a message to given folder

```
INSERT INTO Message (FolderID, Sender, Content) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
```

Delete a message

```
DELETE FROM Message WHERE ID = ?
```

You get the idea.

Now Slick allows you to do these exact operations directly in scala.

First we create the model

```
case class Folder(id:Int, name:String)
case class Message(id:Int, folderID:Int, sender:String, content:String)
```

Then we create the table definitions

```
class FolderTbl extends Table[Folder]("Folder") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def name = column[String]("Name")
  def * = id ~ name <> (Folder.apply _, Folder.unapply _)
}
val FolderTbl = new FolderTbl()
class MessageTbl extends Table[Message]("Message") {
  def id = column[Int]("ID", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def folderID = column[Int]("FolderID")
  def sender = column[String]("Sender")
  def content = column[String]("Content")
  def * = id ~ folderID ~ sender ~ content <> (Folder.apply _, Folder.unapply _)
  def folder = foreignKey("fk_msg_folder", folderID, FolderTbl)(_.id)
}
val MessageTbl = new MessageTbl()
```

And now we can do the queries from before using slick. For example:

```
val query = for {
  msg <- MessageTbl if msg.folderID === someFolder.ID
} yield msg
val lst : List[Message] query.list() //list all messages in a folder
```

So no, slick doesn't allow you to do things automagically, it is more of an improved SQL. But it gives you greater control over what your code does and when.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I got the concept.